# How to filter all the elements from a list of hashmaps given another list? Clojure

Tags: clojure

Consider the following:

```
list of hashmaps '({:key 1 :other-key "hello"} {:key 2 :other-key "bye"})
some list of keys: '(1)
;; I want the result to be:
[{:key 1 :other-key "hello"}]
```

Is there a simple way to filter this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
(def l1 '({:key 1, :other-key "hello"} {:key 2, :other-key "bye"}))
(def l2 '(1))

(filter #(contains? (set l2) (:key %)) l1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ended up doing something like this:

```
(filter #(some #{(:key %)} some-list) list-of-hashmaps)
```